# Flash and camera shutter not in time

Tags: canon, film, flash, godox, wireless

I’ve searched far and wide but cannot find an answer. I recently purchased godox ct-16 to trigger my flash off the camera (canon a1). It worked perfectly on my digital camera and I copied the manual settings over to my canon a1 but resulted in completely black shots. My flash sync speed was correct, 1/60th, the shutter went off and took the photo and the flash went off. Took me a while but I’ve found out that the flash is firing AFTER (late) my shutter has opened and closed so it’s not capturing the flash light (thanks iPhone 240fps slomo lol). Any ideas on why this would be? It syncs perfectly in time with the digital. It’s a Nissin i40 for micro four thirds if that matters but I don’t think it should because I’m just using it in manual on both cameras.

Comment: Is your camera set for second curtain synch?

Answer (score 1):

The *fastest* sync speed for the A1 is 1/60 with a Canon TTL flash (199A); but you may need to use a slower sync speed, especially with the flash off camera (communication delay).

Note that radio triggers can have dead/weak zones depending on the antenna orientation and distance to the receiver... I have no idea about the CT-16's; I didn't even know Godox made them.